# Jquery find class with a certain text and change the css of the parent class if conditions are true

Tags: jquery

I am trying to achieve the following using Jquery but I am not sure how to go about doing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
<script>
$a = array(1,2);

if ($('.box:contains($a)')){
    $('.inbox' //the .inbox where .box text = $a).css(//something);
}

</script>

<body>
<div class='inbox'>
    <div class='box'>1</div>
</div>

<div class='inbox'>
    <div class='box'>2</div>
</div>

<div class='inbox'>
    <div class='box'>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: $a = array(1,2); is not good synthax, should be $a = new Array(1,2); or $a = [1, 2];

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $a = [1, 2];
  $('.box').each(function () {
    if ($.inArray(parseInt(this.innerText), $a) > -1) {
      $(this).closest('.inbox').css({
        border: "5px solid red"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Check the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/johnbk/TTjY7/)

Comment: @roasted - thanks, missed the point the OP want to apply the css to parent element, edited my code.

Comment: Hi everyone thank you for your reply!! I have tried out the code but it is not working for me. The result I am expecting is that the border of .inbox with the number 1 and 2 is in will turn red. Assuming my css.('border', '5px solid red'). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Lynnie - Check my updated answer, included a working fiddle for you.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery has a method called .parent() that returns the parent element.

e.g:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span:contains("foo")').parent().css('color', 'red');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <span>foo</span>
</div>

<div>
    <span>bar</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Ghabriel, thanks for your reply. But ":contains" doesn't seem to be able to take a variable for some reason.